# Can you implement autorenewing subscriptions in codenameone without a server side

Tags: java, mysql, codenameone

I have followed the Auto renewing app subscriptions documentation. However the app i am building does not have a server side right now as it stands. I am failing to see if its possible to create the app without the need for the database at all

I have tried simply calling the Purchase.subscribe methods without any saving to a database

```
public void start() {

    Form hi = new Form("Hello World");
    //create receiptes store 
    Purchase.getInAppPurchase().setReceiptStore(createReceieptsStore());
    //create a button to purchase the world
    Button buyWorld = new Button("Buy World");
    buyWorld.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (Purchase.getInAppPurchase().isSubscribed(SKU)) {
            Dialog.show("Cant Buy It", "You Own It", "OK", null);
        } else {
            Purchase.getInAppPurchase().subscribe(SKU);
        }
    });

    hi.addComponent(buyWorld);
    hi.show();
}
```

I got an error pertaining to the receipt store fetch and submit methods needing to be implemented

Comment: What's inside `createReceieptsStore` did you implement it?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog would it be advisable to use subscriptions without a database ?

Comment: Depending on how painful it would be if someone steals from you. As long as you don't care it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to implement subscription without a server but it would be very easy to hack this on any rooted Android device.